# Replace IdentityServer4 Login Page with Angular component

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I want to use IdentityServer4 (Code + PKCE flow) with .Net Core and Angular.

Instead of using Quickstart UI I want to have log in process on Angular side. In the official tutorial a user goes to Angular app, gets redirect to IdentityServer4 UI, log in there and then there's another redirect - back to Angular app. I also want to mention that I'm not using .net identity and entity framework, since database flow relies on stored procedures.

In my setup I've got Identiy Server running on port 5555 and Angular App running on port 4200. To communicate with the Server I'm using oidc-client-js.

I've created a sample endpoint (Login) that I call from Angular. Unfortunately IdSr doesn't redirect my to the AuthCallbackComponent. I just get an empty response (as expected) but nothing more is happening. As I understand it, after mocking logging the user I just need to raise the UserLoginSuccessEvent. After that IdSr should generate the token and make a redirect. Am I missing something? Is there something wrong in my approach?

```
export class AuthService {
  private userManager: UserManager;
  private user: User;

  constructor(private client: HttpClient) {
    this.userManager = new UserManager(AuthSettings.settings);
    this.userManager.getUser().then(user => (this.user = user));
  }

  login() {
    let api = "http://localhost:5555/api/User";
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
    let content = {
      UserName: "test@test.com",
      Id: "123456",
      Name: "Test User"
    };
    let data = `"${content}"`;
    console.log("logging");
    this.client
      .post(api, content, {
        headers: headers,
        withCredentials: false
      })
      .subscribe(response => console.log(response), err => console.log(err));
  }

  async completeAuthentication() {
    this.user = await this.userManager.signinRedirectCallback();
  }
}



import { UserManagerSettings } from "oidc-client";

export class AuthSettings {
  public static settings: UserManagerSettings = {
    authority: "http://localhost:5555/",
    client_id: "ng",
    redirect_uri: "http://localhost:4200/callback",
    post_logout_redirect_uri: "http://localhost:4200/",
    response_type: "code",
    scope: "openid profile email API"
  };
}


export class AuthCallbackComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService
      .completeAuthentication()
      .then(e => console.log("auth completed"));
  }
}


public static IEnumerable < Client > GetClients() {
    return new List < Client > {
        new Client {
            ClientId = "ng",
            ClientName = "Angular",
            AllowedScopes = {
                "openid",
                "profile",
                "email",
                "API"
            },
            RedirectUris = new List < string > {
                "http://localhost:4200/callback"
            },
            PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List < string > {
                "http://localhost:4200/"
            },
            AllowedCorsOrigins = new List < string > {
                "http://localhost:4200"
            },
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
            RequirePkce = true,
            RequireClientSecret = false,
            AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
            RequireConsent = false
        }
    };
}


[AllowAnonymous][HttpPost]
public async Task < ActionResult > Login(LoginInputModel model) {
    var user = new User("test@test.com", "123456", "Test User");
    await _eventService.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent(user.UserName, user.Id, user.Name));
    return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In the nicest possible way, yes there's something wrong with your approach ;)

If following current best practice for JS client side apps then you should be using the `authorization_code` grant type with a public client (i.e. no secret). User authentication will involve a redirect to the `authorize` endpoint in your `identityserver4` implementation (which may in turn present a login UI if no session exists).

If you want to handle the login UI in your client then this would typically involve using the `ResourceOwnerPassword` grant type which is strongly discouraged. See here:

https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications

However there's nothing to stop you from writing a nice whizzy Angular UI for your `identityserver4` service should you wish. Just be wary of introducing CSRF issues.

Either way, there's no need to create any custom API endpoints to facilitate the sign in process - the `authorize`, `token` and `userinfo` OIDC endpoints have you covered.

Comment: I forgot to mention that - I want to stick with Code + PKCE flow and use angular component for login instead of idenityserver login views. What do you mean that "there's no need to create any custom API endpoints to facilitate the sign in process" ? I have to somehow check if user exists in the database (and pass login and password to that endpoint).

Comment: @dawzaw ah so the above code is on your identity server? If so, I misunderstood. If that's the case then you'd need to establish an authentication cookie via backend call and then redirect to the originally requested URL (via the `returnUrl` query string parameter. The `authorize` endpoint will then pick up that cookie and do the necessary. Don't forget to implement CSRF protection on any backend calls involving cookies - the authentication cookie cannot have a samesite policy set.

Comment: Yes it is on identity server. How does the authorize endpoint pick that cookie? The [documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/endpoints/authorize.html) of the endpoint has no info about it. So after I provide that cookie the code flow will happen behind the scenes since I set up the client (via oidc-client-js)?

Comment: I guess it's assumed that anything implementing `identityserver4` will have a cookie authentication scheme in place - it can't work without that. So yes, once that cookie is in place the `authorize` endpoint will be able to do its thing, return the `code` to the client and the client will be able to redeem the code at the `token` endpoint. The flow is: client -> `authorize` -> sign in UI -> call to endpoint to set auth cookie -> redirect back to `authorize` -> `authorize` redirects to client -> client redeems token via `token` endpoint -> client calls api with `access_token`